# crear PDF en LARAVEL 6: No entiendo cual TCPDF se debe instalar

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-6, tcpdf

Estuve investigando sobre como implementar TCPDF en LARAVEL 6, pero los resultados me dio para instalar
este:"elibyy/tcpdf-laravel", o este: "villca/tcpdf-laravel".

Trate de investigar sus diferencias pero la verdad no encontré y no se cual es el que se debe implementar al LARAVEL 6.

Agradecería si alguien me pudiera informar y de antemano ¡Gracias!...

Comment: Puede ser cualquiera. Revisando ambos noto que [elibyy /tcpdf-laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel) tiene mas instalaciones activas lo que te dara un mayor soporte y documentación de problemas. Pero prueba ambas y decide por el que se te acomode mejor.

Comment: Tu pregunta luce basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre

Comment: No se si sea "Opiniones" por que literalmente estoy preguntando cual se instala ya que no se cual... Recién voy a prender a hacer PDFs

Comment: Precisamente por eso es basada en opiniones por qué depende de lo que sepa y use cada usuario será entonces las respuestas que obtengas, algunos otros quizás hasta te recomienden usar otros paquetes

Comment: Comprendo. Ewg, nunca eh sabido como usar esta plataforma, cada que pregunto algo esta mal...
Solo quería empezar por algo al aprender a implementar TCPDF. Gracias

Comment: Cómo te recomiendo el otro usuario prueba ambas y verifica cual es el mejor a tus necesidades, revisa si es actualizado de forma periódica el paquete o luce abandonado, si los issues son resueltos o no, etc. No te podemos dar una sola respuesta por qué depende